# How to execute a search and command containing `<C-..>` within a function?

Tags: regex, search, vim, special-characters, wrapper

I still struggle executing commands from within a function:

**Function**:

```
 function! MyFunc(key)
  let r = a:key
  exe r
 endfun
```

`a:key` can be anything but when it is a search or a command containing `<C-..>` it doesn't work

1)
**special keys example**
When `a:key` = `'normal \<C-w>t\<C-w>H'`
it does `exe 'normal \<C-w>t\<C-w>H'` in above function
it has to be `exe "normal \<C-w>t\<C-w>H"` (double quotes)
How can I execute special keys from a variable (a:key)/ function call?

2) 
**highlighting example**
When I call this function from the commandline `:call MyFunc('/\s')`
even if highlighting is on, I have to push the `n` key to see the items found highlighted
or an alternative is to check within the function if `r` starts with `/` then do `return normal! n`
How can I avoid this?
This has the same effect:
`:call MyFunc('let @/ = "\\s"')`

How do I exec special keys and search items from a function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE 1. You have to pass in the special keys to your function in the final form, e.g.

```
:call MyFunc("normal \<C-w>t\<C-w>H")
```

RE 2. Inside functions, the last used search pattern will not be changed (cp. `:h function-search-undo`). This is a feature, not a bug. To work around that, you have to execute the command outside the function (i.e. directly in the command or mapping); you can still invoke a function to generate the search pattern, though.

Comment: Hello Ingo, tnx for replying. 1) I tried your example in above function from the vim commandline. It gives an error: `E492: Not an editor command: ^Wt^WH` Did I something wrong? 2) If a search pattern is a result of the output of a function, how can I put it back in a command?

Comment: 1) There's a `:normal` missing (either in the function or the argument passed to it); adapted the answer. 2) `let @/ = MyFunc(...)`

Comment: ad 1) please see my question. ad 2) you mean subsitute `call MyFunc()` with `let @/ = MyFunc()`

Comment: 1) What gets passed is `normal ^Wt^WH` (with `^W` being one character), and `:exe` (inside the function) should be able to interpret that. Apart from that, I see no other possibility. 2) yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: 1)found it.. your\my command works from the vim commandline but not from within the menu: `an 90.00.00 &Test.Test\  :call MyFunc("normal \<C-w>t\<C-w>H")<CR>` Double escaping also doesn't work. 2) I tried this, but still no higlighting. Maybe because I'm using subs in the function?

Comment: Menus are like mappings; I think you have to write `an 90.00.00 &Test.Test\ :call MyFunc("normal \<lt>C-w>t\<lt>C-w>H")<CR>`

Comment: Yes! thank you. I wish I could find also a solution for this highlighting thing.

Comment: Ingo, This one doesn't seem to work from within menu `:call MyFunc("normal \<lt>C-r>\"")<CR>` --> `<C-R>"`